# How to replace sections of a database with Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace different sections of a DB with certain values. Normally for this use I'd use the .fillna() function however I need to replace different parts of the database with different values. Here is the DB:

```
                Base        T1
Date                          
2020-02-25  0.962385       NaN
2020-02-26  0.958845       NaN
2020-02-27  0.915782       NaN
2020-02-28  0.911934       NaN
2020-03-02  0.951427  1.000000
2020-03-03  0.924185  0.977315
2020-03-04  0.963031  0.982521
2020-03-05  0.931019  0.946077
2020-03-06  0.915628  0.906037
2020-03-09  0.844122  0.814801
2020-03-10  0.887801       NaN
2020-03-11  0.844522       NaN
2020-03-12  0.763721       NaN
2020-03-13  0.829009       NaN
```

I would like to replace all of the NaN values before 2020-03-02 with 1 and replace all the NaN values after 2020-03-09 with 0.829009 . I'm not entirely sure how to go about this. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with boolean masking with `loc` accessor:

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.loc[(df.index<'2020-03-02') & (df['T1'].isna()),'T1']=1
df.loc[(df.index>'2020-03-02') & (df['T1'].isna()),'T1']=0.829009
```